HTML to Docx File - Angular and Laravel
I'm currently doing a project using angular for front-end and laravel to handle my backend (using api). One of the requirements is to display a preview of a word document file, and should be allowed to do rich text editing (mainly highlight some texts) since one of the system requirements is to do checking document by highlighting text with errors. We will not use a library for the rich-text editor, but would use one for exporting it to docx. My problem is how do I export an html file to docx without compromising its style? WYSIWYG. My html file has tables and pictures as well.

I have a template docx (which i am willing to code to html if i were to find an html-> docx without changing the styles.
Only some of the data will be changed in docx.

I tried:

Coding the certificate template in angular. I made the areas that will be dynamic to reactive form.
I'm using PHPWord for backend (using templateprocessor too)

So the current workaround is:
I have a coded certificate template for UI purposes only. But still the processing is on the server side which is plotting to template.
I don't know if what I am doing right now is the most practical one. Or is there more efficient way?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
